# count node degree in matlab from a adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab

this is my matrix that displays a sample network graph

```
matrix =

     0     1     1     1
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     0
```

where its a 4x4 matrix

```
       1)    2)    3)    4)       

1)     0     1     1     1
2)     1     0     1     0
3)     0     0     0     1
4)     1     1     1     0
```

i want to count this 4x4 matrix like 
row 1 counts how many 1s i have and adds column 1  number of 1's to it and returns 1)=5 as total 1's in row 1 and col 1 = 5

i want my output to be like

```
1=5 
2=4
3=4
4=5
```

Answer (score 1):

This must be it -

```
out = sum([matrix matrix'],2)
```

Example run -

```
matrix =

     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1

out =

     6
     3
     4
     5
```

The above code would count 1s twice when they appear on the diagonal, which if you don't want, use this -

```
out1 = sum([matrix matrix'],2) - diag(matrix)
```

Example run -

```
matrix =

     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1

out1 =

     5
     3
     4
     4
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of Divakar, but once your graph gets larger and larger, you might not want to transpose the entire matrix. I suggest doing the sum first and then transposing afterwards:

```
    sum(matrix,1)'+sum(matrix,2)-diag(matrix);

    matrix =

              0     1     1     1
              1     0     1     0
              0     0     0     1
              1     1     1     0

    degree=sum(matrix,1)'+sum(matrix,2)-diag(matrix)

    degree =

              5
              4
              4
              5
```